NestJS Cache Manager Overwrites Previous Keys When Storing Unique Values
I'm using NestJS with the built-in CACHE_MANAGER to cache data for each connected client in a WebSocket gateway. The expectation is that each client connection generates a unique key in the cache, and all keys should remain in the store without being overwritten. However, when a new client connects, it seems to overwrite the previous cache entry, even though the keys are different.
Every time when i client is connect with his specific id i store the id using this:
 await this.cacheManager.set(key, value)
, also next i do this.cacheManger.store.keys() where i expect to have 2 entries if i connected 2 users in sockets.
 Question: I expect the .set() method automatically to store multiple entries, but why every next entry overrites previous even with different keys? Every time in result i have only one entry, the last one.
